# Add contact image to MessagingStyle notification 'Person'

Tags: android, notifications

I would like my notifications to include the contact's image.
I am using NotificationCompat and MessagingStyle do display chat messages for contacts.

This works when using the .setIcon on the person, but the image is square, so I would like to use the setUri but it doesn't display the image, instead I see the contact's first initial in a circle.

Here is the code I'm using for the notification.

```
Person person = new Person.Builder()
//                .setIcon(contactIcon)
                .setName(displayName)
                .setUri(contentLookupURI)
                .setKey(contactDetail)
                .build();

NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle chatMessageStyle = new NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle(person);

NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.Message notificationMessage = new
                NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.Message(
                contentText,
                System.currentTimeMillis(),
                person
        );
        chatMessageStyle.addMessage(notificationMessage);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_MESSAGES_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(icon) // notification icon
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setStyle(chatMessageStyle)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setContentTitle(displayName);
```

And for the contact URI used in the `.setUri` I'm using a library to obtain the contact id and lookupkey then use the method:

```
 contactLookupURI = 
 ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri(contactsList.get(0).getId(), 
 contactsList.get(0).getLookupKey());
```

Which produces this: `content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/3118r4-2F294339313F5B16.3789r5-2F294339313F5B16/6` which looks correct to me.

[image: example notification]

I'm not sure how new this form of the MessagingStyle method is as I can't find many examples of it's usage with a Person object.

Comment: what if all the contacts doesn't have an image

Comment: lol @ManojPerumarath, I did check, they do have images, and it works when I use setIcon with the contacts photoURI, I hope that's what you mean

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Comment: @Bink no, I ended up generating and setting the bitmap manually with a RoundedBitmapDrawable

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for those using Remote URL with Glide

Step 1: Get Bitmap from Remote URL

```
private fun getAvatarFromUrl(photoUrl: String): Bitmap? {
        return try {
            val futureTarget = Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(photoUrl)
                .submit()

            futureTarget.get()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.e(e)
            null
        }
    }
```

Step 2: Set Bitmap as Person.Icon

```
val avatar = getAvatarFromUrl(user.avatar)
val sender = Person.Builder()
     .setName(msg.from?.name)
     .setIcon(IconCompat.createWithBitmap(avatar))
     .setImportant(true)
     .build()
```

Comment: I think you've mistaken URL and URI, this question is about a device contact's photo URI

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use resource id instead of bitmap:

```
val person = Person.Builder()
.setName("Name")
.setKey("Key")
.setIcon(IconCompat.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.ic_resource)).build()
```